# Is there a utility similar to Twitter Bootstrap/Foundation5 for WPF files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning C# and the .NET framework.  I have experience in Web Development.  I was just introduced to WPF files, and the drag and drop 'toolbox'.  It seems pretty cumbersome to drag and drop elements and then resize them to look 'pretty' in the application with proper spacing, alignment, etc...

I do not have an eye for making the layout nice, and formatted in an appealing way.

**Question:**
Is there a tool similar to Twitter Bootstrap, or Foundation for constructing WPF files?  Or a template builder I can use to create layouts for my WPF file?  Or use pre-made "pretty" layouts for my WPF file?

Comment: check this out 
[link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPF.Bootstrap/) May be that will help you

Comment: For those who are still interested in the subject. "Modern UI for WPF" mentioned by Sam is not updated since 2016. Take a look at [Material Design In XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit).

Comment: https://github.com/RandyPJ/WPFBootstrapUI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking something like [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui). This open source project provides nice looking layout with beautiful controls.

> A set of controls and styles converting your WPF application into a great looking Modern UI app. This open source project is a spin-off of XAML Spy, the visual runtime inspector for Silverlight, Windows Phone, Windows Store and WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply styles on the WPF controls. It will work like CSS.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/using-styles/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18388/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-Styles

Also you can edit any template, for example a TextBox. Click in your control, right mouse button, then Edit Template.

I use MahApps(http://mahapps.com/) that provides styles and controls to make Metro UI, making your application looks very nice.

Answer (score 2):

I am also beginner in WPF as are you. In My opinion you can use templates for WPF. What Bootstrap provide is java script and CSS for a web project. In WPF we use Resource Dictionaries and Template basically provides it. I use Metro Template for my WPF projects.
May be you find this link helpful - [mahapps.com](http://mahapps.com)